# Can antimatter-matter collisions generate heat?

Tags: energy, antimatter

We have a project at school to develop an idea about how we can generate electricity.

My question is: do collisions between matter and antimatter particles generate heat, so that one could harvest it using turbines?

Comment: Does your school have a reliable inexpensive supply of antimatter?

Comment: Does your school have a gamma radiation hardened bunker that can withstand several megaton blasts and which you can do your project by remote control from? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at first, but usually eventually.

You should read the Wikipedia article on [Annihilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation), which is the name of the phenomenon of a particle's colliding with its anitparticle.

Particles and antiparticles have opposite-signed, equal magnitude quantum numbers (such as spin and parity to name two). Collisions must conserve these quantum numbers, so the peculiar, special case of all quantum numbers summing to nought means that *any* other set of particles with zero sum quantum numbers can emerge from the collision, as long as total energy and momentum are conserved by the collision.

The most common products, though, are pairs of photons with opposite spins, particularly with low energy particles. These are very high frequency photons - gamma rays. Gamma particles are quite penetrating - they can travel deep into matter before being absorbed.

At this point, the absorbed gammas add to the heat of the absorbing matter.

Answer (score 2):

When a particle collides with its antiparticle, all of the mass in both is converted into electromagnetic energy (usually high energy gamma radiation).

Whilst it is certainly possible to then convert this gamma radiation into heat so as to drive a turbine, it may be also possible to convert gamma radiation directly into electricity using a special type of '[nuclear solar panel](http://gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Research%20Papers-Quantum%20Theory%20/%20Particle%20Physics/Download/4362)'.

Comment: *"usually high energy gamma radiation"* Er ... if hadrons are involved there are a lot of pions which means that a lot of the energy ends up as neutrinos.